# Which AndroidManifest.xml to edit in Flutter project?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I notice there are several `AndroidManifest.xml`s under `android/app/src`, `debug`, `main`, and `profile` folders all contain one. Which one to edit?

[image]

Comment: As answers say you want to focus on the main manifest, however I suspect that 99.99% of the cases the debug and profile manifests are just semi empty stubs, because they don't modify anything over the main manifests. So maybe I should just delete them? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75831814/why-flutter-android-directory-has-3-manifests-when-i-can-build-with-just-one

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Main `AndroidManifest.xml` file is located at **'Project' > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml.**

Other `AndroidManifest.xml` which are in debug folder and profile folder are systems generated when you are running a flutter app directly to mobile it will generate or while creating a flutter project. E.g: It is used for hot reload when the device is connected.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and enter `androidmanifest.xml`, now open the one located at **`android/app/src/main`**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change your App name, Package name / different permissions you want in your app you have to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` which is inside the main folder

Comment: So is the version in `main` used even when you're running in `debug` mode? What information should go in the other two manifest files? Does the `debug` profile inherit from the `main` profile, i.e. `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` contains a set of overrides that replace things in the `main` version?